# Loop always executing twice

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I'm currently doing a school project and in that project I have to ask the user his/her gender and then display an error which works. But for some reason the loop always executes twice before letting the user input again.
example:

```
Veuillez entrer le sex de l'individu f/F ou h/H: e

Erreur veuillez entrer des valeurs valides
Veuillez entrer le sex de l'individu f/F ou h/H: 

Erreur veuillez entrer des valeurs valides
Veuillez entrer le sex de l'individu f/F ou h/H:
```

and here is the code

```
 System.out.println ("Veuillez entrer le sex de l'individu f/F ou h/H: "); //first time asking for user input
 sex = Clavier.lireChar();

 while ((sex != ('f') || sex != ('F')) || (sex != ('h') || sex != ('H'))){ 
       System.out.println ("Erreur veuillez entrer des valeurs valides");  //error message
       System.out.println ("Veuillez entrer le sex de l'individu f/F ou h/H: "); //asking for user inoput again
       sex = Clavier.lireChar();
 }
 if (sex == ('f') || sex == ('F')) {
       nbFemmes = nbFemmes + 1;
 } else if (sex == ('h') || sex == ('H')) {
       nbHommes = nbHommes +1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you press `f` followed by Enter, you have pressed two keys and therefore get two `char`s, one lowercase letter f (`'f'`) and one linefeed/newline character (`'\n'`).

You can similarly enter `abc` and press enter, and you'll see it loops 4 times instead of 1.

You can fix this in one of two ways. The easiest is probably to read a `char` by reading an entire line and then only using the first letter. I don't know what this `Clavier` class is, but if it's similar to [this one](http://lig-membres.imag.fr/genoud/ENSJAVA/tds/sujets/td2/docs/LectureClavier.html) you can use something like:

```
sex = Clavier.lireChaine().charAt(0);
```

Alternatively, you can keep reading single characters until you get something that is not a linefeed:

```
while ((sex = Clavier.lireChar()) == '\n');
```

It will now no longer loop twice for every attempt, but due to [the problem mentioned by Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60081763/1899640), it'll keep asking forever and never accept any input because if you enter `f` then `sex != 'h'` is true, and if you enter `h` then `sex != 'f'` is true, and either condition causes the loop to repeat.

Comment: yeah I already fixed the problem mentioned by Tushar but because of the restriction my teacher gave us I'll try the second solution since she won't allow the first one.

Comment: so I understand what you are trying to do with '\n' but im not sure where I should insert `while ((sex = Clavier.lireChar()) != '\n');` for it to work

Comment: @zactrixo I accidentally used `!=` instead of `==`. You can replace `sex = Clavier.lireChar();` with `while ((sex = Clavier.lireChar()) == '\n');` wherever you use it

Comment: Thank you it worked I just hope its a valid solution!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your while condition logic. Try the following and make sure you understand it. Let me know if you don't understand the conditional logic. Happy coding!

```
while ((sex != ('f') && sex != ('F')) && (sex != ('h') && sex != ('H'))){ 
   System.out.println ("Erreur veuillez entrer des valeurs valides");  //error message
   System.out.println ("Veuillez entrer le sex de l'individu f/F ou h/H: "); //asking for user inoput again
   sex = Clavier.lireChar();
}
```

Comment: I understand why you are using && instead of || but even with your solution it still repeats the loop two times before asking for input again.

Comment: if you enter any of character from h,H,f,F the loop will exits, this is what you want right?

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I need.

Comment: ok, then the problem is with your input function. try the solution provided by @that other guy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably late to the party, here's another solution.

As a couple of the people mentioned, the issue looks to be with your condition inside the while loop.

I'm a bit concerned that your teacher doesn't allow use of scanner, though!

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println ("Veuillez entrer le sex de l'individu f/F ou h/H: ");

char sex = in.next().charAt(0); 

while (sex != 'f' && sex != 'F' && sex != 'h' && sex != 'H' ){ 
System.out.println ("Erreur veuillez entrer des valeurs valides");  //error message
System.out.println ("Veuillez entrer le sex de l'individu f/F ou h/H: "); //asking for user input again
sex = in.next().charAt(0); 
}

// If we reached here, this means we have good input.

if (sex == ('f') || sex == ('F')) {
 // Do something
} else if (sex == ('h') || sex == ('H')) {
 // Do something
}
```

Comment: yeah I dont know why she doesn't want us to use scanner its but as I said earlier I also can't use `char sex = in.next().charAt(0);` but I'll keep doing what I can and ask one of the helpers at school for a solution.

Comment: @zactrixo Sure thing. Not sure what point your teacher is trying to prove. Best of luck!